# URI/Hyperlink to Bot created using Google Chat API

Tags: google-hangouts

We would like to add a hyperlink in our intranet which when clicked will open google chat conversation with the specified bot developed using Google Chat API.

When creating a chatbot via https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/chat.googleapis.com/hangouts-chat?project=xxxxxxxx, the only identifying information about the bot appears to be an App ID (Project Number) and the Bot name.

As of 2020 version of Google Chat, there appears to be no documentation on how to create a direct URI to a user or bot ID) say something like https://chat.google.com/users/XXXXXXXXX  where XXXXXXXX is the Bot ID

An inspection of the Google Chat Web Widget (https://chat.google.com) roster/contact list when communicating with the bot suggests that bot identifiers are of the form user/bot/114553095703997684XXX or user/114553095703997684XXX where 114553095703997684XXX is the App Id referenced earlier.

How can we programmatically construct a direct URI to the chat bot given its App ID or Name?

Comment: Have you tried using a room where the bot is invited?

Comment: The bot in question is a Personal Scope bot reachable by Direct Messages (DM).  A DM ID is visible in the URI but that is unique to the user/caller and not universal.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no method to create a URL that opens a space with a user or bot.
To get a list of spaces you would need to already be part of one.

I would suggest creating a Feature Request if you have not yet. [Create an Issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui#create_an_issue) and submit it as a Feature Request.